# Is there any place where Shulchan Aruch rules with the Rosh against the Rif and Rambam?

Tags: rambam, shulchan-aruch, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi, rabbeinu-asher

I am arguing with a friend about whether the Shulchan Aruch, being Sepharadi, weighed Sepharadi poskim higher than Ashkenazi ones. The above question came up.

Comment: The rule which he wrote in his hakdama ,is he goes after majority of the 3,but we see that he paskens somtimes like the Rambam stam

Comment: And sometimes he goes after the minhag, regardless of the majority or the Rambam, but that was not my question.

Comment: Also why are you considering the Rosh as a Ashkenazi ,he was became Rav in Spain and had what to do with the Rashba,even though he learnt ny the Mahrahm.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to also inquire if he ever ruled with any of those 3 against the other two? Would it matter if there were different amounts of times that he ever chose to follow a single opinion? Dioraisa's or DiRabanan's? Lichatchila or Bidieved? I think any source you get won't settle your argument.

Answer (score 10):

The Shulchan Arukh (OC 259:1) rules like Rosh, against Rif and Rambam, that wool shearings used to insulate a pot before Shabbat are not Muktza even if they weren't designated as insulation as long as they weren't designated as a commodity to be sold. This is one of the examples Rama, in his introduction to Darkei Moshe, gives in critique of the Beit Yosef.

Answer (score -1):

Bracha on 2 cups of wine vs. all 4 cups at the Seder.

Comment: What do all the relevant parties hold?

Comment: Nearly all Geonim - 4 brachot; Rambam-  - 4, Rif - 4; Rabbenu Yona and Rosh, with Rashba - only 2.

Comment: Where do they all make these rulings

Comment: Rambam, Hilchot CHametz uMatzah, 7:10

Comment: Piskei HaRosh has the Rosh and quotes the Rif there.

Comment: Rif Pesachim 24

Comment: Jeffery, please [edit] all relevant info into your post so everyone can see it